# Flutter - implementing radial gradient button from figma

Tags: flutter, dart, radial-gradients, figma

I'm trying to implement the below design in Figma. The inspect panel of Figma gives CSS codes for this button as below:

```
// COLORS:
// background: linear-gradient(0deg, #FF7966, #FF7966),
// radial-gradient(111.2% 100% at 50% 100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50.52%, rgba(255, 127, 55, 0.5) 100%),
// linear-gradient(153.43deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 83.33%);

// BORDERS:
// border: 1px solid;
// border-image-source: linear-gradient(153.43deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 83.33%);

// SHADOWS
// box-shadow: 0px 8px 25px 0px #FF796680;
```

But I think the radial gradient in Figma is not a circle, is there any way to change the shape of the radial gradient in Flutter? You can find DartPad link here:

https://dartpad.dev/?id=ec3b820dd5a31c8aafce0f9f9aff037d

[image: Figma Design]

Answer (score 0):

You can use "**LinearGradient**" instead of "**RadialGradient**"

Replace your gradient property, inside your BoxDecoration for:

```
LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            colors: [
              Colors.white.withOpacity(0.0),
              const Color(0xFFFF7F37),
            ],           
          ),
```

Comment: I don't see the changes. I think you can't save the changes in DartPad. It is working with GitHub gist as following: https://gist.github.com/anilcngz/ec3b820dd5a31c8aafce0f9f9aff037d
Can you paste your code here?

Comment: I'm sorry, I  edited and wrote an example of LinearGradient usage